# Is it possible to run a python machine learning script from an iOS app in swift?

Tags: python, ios, swift, machine-learning

I'm trying to code an iOS app that takes 11 metrics of patient data as input, and outputs the probability a patient has heart disease. I already coded the deep learning model to make this prediction, and have it stored as a .py script.

How do I set up a routine to call this python script from a button click within the app, and then display the output to the screen?

I read some conflicting information about whether it is possible to run a .py file within Xcode / swift, or if it needs to be in Tensorflow or Keras.

Currently my code is all in numpy - for it to be called by the app, does it need to be in Tensorflow or Keras?

Thank you!

Comment: You could do something like dev in Cordova and use a library such as this pypi.org/project/python-cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to run a `*.py` script locally, but for sure you can call it as a URL and have the server do the work for you, then return the results. Something like this:

```
let myURLString = "https://www.server.com/script.py"

if let
    url = URL(string: myURLString),
    contents = try? String(contentsOfURL: url) {
        print(contents)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the procedure to call it as a URL, and which server are you referring to? I made the deep learning software available on AWS with a login system and GUI if that is relevant...

Comment: Minor item, but there is no need to use NSURL with modern Swift, URL is sufficient.

Comment: The AWS should have an address, use that for `myURLString`, and if you've exposed the functionality as a service, you're all set. If not, then that's another issue. Use POST or GET to pass credentials and I recommend a secure protocol.